# How can I copy in data to submit to form one by one?

Tags: javascript, web

I have a webpage I am working with with, where the task is to enter some data into two textboxes and click on the Add button to add the data to the list. I was looking for a possible way to automate this.

I have learned that the following code can do that if entered in the console.

```
document.getElementById("textbox1").value="value1"; 

document.getElementById("textbox2").value="value2"; 

javascript:addRow(document.form1, 1);
```

So this is all pretty basic. I have all of the values in an excel sheet, with all my value1 data in one column, and all my value2 data in another. I dont see how I can run all of this at the same time, as the addRow refreshes the page and will reset any script. Does anyone know what would be a good way to do this?

Comment: How are you getting information from Excel into the page in this way?

Comment: If you don't know about jQuery, try going through this 'class' http://try.jquery.com/ I think it might be helpful for you. As far as what your goal is, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @JimPedid so far I have been copying and pasting the values from excel into the text boxes.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth What else should I add?

Comment: @JeremyRowler What are you doing with the data? What's your end goal? Are you manipulating the data on the fly to new outputs?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth The only Thing I am doing with the Data is copying it into the text boxes and submitting it.

Comment: @JeremyRowler Are you designing the site, or just using it?

Comment: unfortunately just using it, I would have designed it much differently

Comment: I would look into a tool like selenium webdriver and run a script on your machine that will drive the webpage. If you're familiar with ruby, the watir-webdriver library is a pretty convenient wrapper over selenium that will let you automate web pages for things like tests, etc. The overall approach would be to use an API to read from the excel file, and then use the web-driver API to do things on the page with that information.